# java, bit operation, how to calculate the length back?

Tags: java

In a java programe, people store data in a byte array, and the first two byte were used to store the length of data,

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
int size = data.getBytes().length;

buffer[0] = (byte)((size >> 8 ) &  0xff);
buffer[1] = (byte)(size & 0xff);
```

now given value of `buffer[0]` and `buffer[1]`, how to get `size` back?

Answer (score 0):

All such things are described in `DataInputStream/DataOutputStream` java classes a long time ago. More specifically in your task it will be:

```
return (short)(((int)(buffer[0] & 0xff) << 8) + ((int)(buffer[1] & 0xff) << 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getSize(byte [] buffer)
{
  return (buffer[0] << 8) | (buffer[1] << 0);
}
```

Comment: Also write brief about the solution you are suggesting!